# Use Xpath to get content from linked file in current XML document

Tags: xml, xpath, feed

I have an XML doc which is a feed of excerpts of all blog entries, and in each entry there is a link to another XML file which holds the full content to that particular entry (bigger images, full text, etc.). Is it possible to access those inner XML docs and get values from it using XPATH?

The main document looks something like this:

```
    <Objects>
              <Item xml="doc.xml"></Item>  
                      // I would want to be able to access content 
                      // inside the document at Item/@xml
              <Item xml="doc2.xml"></Item>
    </Objects>
```

Comment: If I am using .NET (and due to some strange reason I am forbidden to use XSLT), I would set variables in the XPath evaluation context and specify as their values the two XML documents (already parsed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$feed = "http://example.com/feed.xml";
if (file_exists($feed)) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $Objects = $xml->xpath('//Objects/Item[@xml]');
    foreach ($Objects as $O) {
$feed2 = "http://example.com/".$O."";
}

if (file_exists($feed2)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed2);
$feed2path = $xml->xpath('//*/*');
echo $feed2path[@someid];
}

} 
?>
```

something like this using two xpaths and a for each?

Comment: I ended up hacking the module I was using and pasting a version of this in. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `document` function, but I don't know if you can do exactly what you are describing

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt/

Comment: The `document()` function is a standard XSLT function -- it isn't available in pure XPath 1.0. XPath 2.0 has a `doc()` function, however it seems that the OP needs an XPath 1.0 solution.

Comment: Exactly. I've tried doc() and that doesn't work, so it has to be 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value from your attribute when using the document() function.

This small example works well for me:

#### Static.xml with xml reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cartoon2html.xsl"?>
<xml xml="cartoons.xml"/>
```

#### The actual XML

```
<cartoons>
    <cartoon name="Donald Duck" publisher="Walt Disney" />
    <cartoon name="Mickey Mouse" publisher="Walt Disney" />
    <cartoon name="Batman" publisher="DC Comics" />
    <cartoon name="Superman" publisher="DC Comics" />
    <cartoon name="Iron Man" publisher="Marvel Comics" />
    <cartoon name="Spider-Man" publisher="Marvel Comics" />
</cartoons>
```

#### The XSL using the value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="document" select="/xml/@xml" />
    <xsl:variable name="cartoons" select="document($document)/cartoons" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Cartoons</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$cartoons" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cartoons">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cartoon">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@publisher" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Running the sample

You can run this using xsltproc:  # xsltproc cartoon2html.xsl static.xml

You can also open the static.xml file in your firefox browser.

Comment: This is an XPath question -- not an XSLT question.